# Docusign "Could Not load file or Assembly Restsharp" Error

Tags: c#, .net-core, docusignapi

I'm using Docusign in my (.netcore 3.1) project and I'm also using another nuget package which relies on minio. 
Both seem to rely on Restsharp.

When I try to run my app I'm getting this error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=106.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)'
```

Docusign Version: 4.4.1

This is a screenshot of the dependencies as viewed from visual studio:
[image]

[image]

I've tried adding this binding redirect in App.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" publicKeyToken="598062e77f915f75" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-106.3.1.0" newVersion="106.10.1" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This has had no impact whatsoever. Please can you help me. Any help very much appreciated! :)

Comment: when i get stuck trying to work out where something is looking for a file (like here) I fire up procmon from sysinternals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version of the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/) fixes this problem. Please check latest version 4.4.1 has the fix.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I dealt with it recently as well.

Comment: can you please marked this question as answered or upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

The 4.4.1 version of the C# SDK depends on the specific version of RestSharp.dll, it must use version 106.3.1.0. A later version would not work.
This is a known issue and would probably only get fixed in version 4.5.0, and I don't know when that version would be released at this time.
The only workaround is to find restsharp.dll version 106.3.1.0 and add it as a reference or put it in the same folder so that it can be loaded (was going to say put it in the GAC but you're using .NET Core).

Revision: actually, if you want to build your own version of DocuSign.eSign.dll, you can go to https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client and build the code yourself.